# Creating multiple folders named by a list in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to make a python code to create folders named by a list of int and strings, the code below is returning an error, it works when the list is made of strings only, can anybody help ?

```
import os
root_path = 'C:\Users\AHemeda\Desktop'
folders = [123, 34, 'Oslo', 'Berlin']
gh = folders
print gh
for folder in gh:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))
```

Comment: Your root path is incorrect, try: `r'C:\Users\AHemeda\Desktop'`

Comment: This should really be on Stack Overflow instead of GIS.SE.

Answer (score 3):

Try casting the variable as a string:

```
for folder in gh:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,str(folder)))
```